# Issue connecting migrated .net site to MySQL db on Synology NAS using Web Service and myPHPAdmin

Tags: mysql, .net, phpmyadmin, database-connection, synology

I migrated an existing .NET site and db but was asked to move it to a Synology NAS box. The site is up and running and I've added users to the to the db using myPHPAdmin but I'm unable (or don't know how) to connect the db to the site in this environment. There is a un and pw box on the site but the button is unpressable after the migration. Below is the old appsettings json for the site. The image repository line has been changed but the imager connection string is old and I'm not sure what this now needs to be or if this is the correct route to fix the issue.  I'm a little out of my element on this synology box, any and all suggestion/direction is greatly appreciated. Ty

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "imager": "Server=DATABASE_URL;Database=DATABASE_NAME;User Id=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD;"
  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ImageRepository": "/web/visionboard/wwwroot/images/repo"
}
```

Comment: Please, examine and share logs

Comment: The log center in the Synology box is severely lacking. I'll try turning this logging level to debug and see what I can pull there. Thank you

Comment: The specific issue I'm having now is the db path for this connection string. Using phpMyAdmin on the synology box.

Comment: You might use phpMyAdmin to interface with the MySQL or MariaDB server, but that's not what your application will use. You should point it directly to the MySQL/MariaDB instance, which is probably exposed on port 3306 if you're accessing it across the network or through the localhost socket if connecting locally. phpMyAdmin is a graphical interface for you to manage a database server, but doesn't provide the API for your application to talk directly to the database.

Comment: If the application is running on the same system as the database, try using 'localhost' as the host (you'll have to know the other values, for database name, username, and password since we couldn't know those). It might help if you tell us what application you're using or what platform runs the site (or is it a completely custom .Net application?) and perhaps tell us more about the button that's greyed out. It sounds a bit strange, because most applications wouldn't try to connect until you press the button, so it shouldn't yet know it can't connect to the database. More details would help.